# Numpy Array Problem with Calculation, int type, int32 vs int64

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, calculation

I don't know why there is a discrepancy between the two lines of code below. The Numpy array (i.e., "load_values") for some reason is slightly off in the calculation? When I replace the Numpy array index with the actual value that is stored (in this case, 1800), I get the correct answer. Also, I replaced the Numpy array with a regular List and it also got the correct answer. It's only when I use the Numpy array that I am getting the calculation slightly off. Any reason why this would be the case? Is it obvious and I'm just not seeing it?

```
In [27]: alpha[3] + alpha[2] * 1800 + alpha[1] * (1800 ** 2) + alpha[0] * (1800 ** 3)

Out[27]: 1.2057057142857146

In [28]: alpha[3] + alpha[2] * load_values[2] + alpha[1] * (load_values[2] ** 2) + alpha[0] * (load_values[2] ** 3)

Out [28]: 1.2048772097918872
```

Edit: Here are the alpha and load_values:

```
In[54]: alpha

Out[54]: array([ 4.24382716e-13, -1.18055556e-09, -6.69194444e-04,  1.64000000e-03])

In[55]: load_values

Out[55]: array([ 600, 1200, 1800, 2400, 3000])
```

Comment: Can you share what is stored in `alpha` and `load_values`?

Comment: It would seem that `load_values[2]` does not contain _exactly_ 1800. Have you tried doing `load_values[2] = 1800` before the calculation? The only difference I can think of is that `1800 ** 2` and `1800 ** 3` will do an integer exponentiation, but that should not be imprecise with 32- or 64-bit floats anyway.

Comment: (as an example, consider that `np.array([1800. + 1e-12])[0] == 1800` is `False`, but printing that array shows `[1800.]`)

Comment: @Daniel, I provided the values stored in the arrays above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the root of the issue is an overflow when doing the operation: `load_values[2] ** 3`. The default int-type for `numpy` appears to be `int32` while the standard python `int` appears to be at least the `numpy.int64` equivalent. You need to use `int64` to properly compute your equation. This can be seen here:

```
# load_values as int32 array (numpy default):
print(type(load_values[2]))  # <class 'numpy.int32'>
print(type(1800))            # <class 'int'>

answer_1 = 1800 ** 3
answer_2 = load_values[2] ** 3

print(answer_1)              # 5832000000
print(answer_2)              # 1537032704


# load_values as int64 array:
load_values = np.array(load_values, dtype=np.int64)

print(type(load_values[2]))  # <class 'numpy.int64'>
print(type(1800))            # <class 'int'>

answer_1 = 1800 ** 3
answer_2 = load_values[2] ** 3

print(answer_1)              # 5832000000
print(answer_2)              # 5832000000
```

I will leave the bit-by-bit analysis up to you.